# Web Scraping with python - Errors Occured

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want to write the code as below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html") 
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
for sibling in bsObj.find("table",{"id":"giftList"}).tr.next_siblings: print(sibling)
```

But whenever I type the line of `bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)`, it throws an error as the following pic:

[image]

Hope anyone can help me out of this.

Thanks

Comment: You have an extra left paren bud

Comment: The code in the question is not the same as the image

Answer (score 0):

```
html = urlopen("http://www.your.url/here")
```

Instead of

```
html = urlopen(("http://www.your.url/here")
```

Notice the `((` to the right of `urlopen`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Don't forget to mark as solved and up-vote if you found my answer helpful.